# Scope in ES6 and jQuery selectors on click functions

Tags: jquery, onclick, click, ecmascript-6

I currently am using jQuery and ES6 to do a simple Read Me toggle.
Here is my code and it works on more than one read more on the page.

```
class ReadMore {
    constructor(cfg) {
        this.toggle = $(cfg.el).find('.read-more-toggle');
        var toggleText = $('.read-more-toggle').text().split(" ")[0];

        $('.read-more-toggle').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if ($(this).hasClass("read-less-toggle")) {
                $(this).parent().prev(".read-more").hide()
                $(this).removeClass("read-less-toggle")
                $(this).text(toggleText + " More");
            } else {
                $(this).parent().prev(".read-more").show();
                $(this).text(toggleText + " Less");
                $(this).addClass("read-less-toggle");
            }
        });
    }
}

export default ReadMore;
```

I was wondering why is it that when I use `this.toggle` it only works on one instance of the `read-more` and not of another instance, but when I use `$('.read-more-toggle')` directly it works. I think I'm a bit confused by the scope.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any advantage from using a `class` here. It doesn't have any methods, and you don't even seem to use the `.toggle` field - so if you don't need to store the instances, just don't create them in the first place and use a simple `function initReadMore(cfg)` instead of that constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` (and therefore by implication, `$(this)`) refers to the single `.read-more-toggle` element which raised the click event.

`$('.read-more-toggle')` refers to all `.read-more-toggle` elements found within the current document.

Hence the former affects only one element, while the latter affects all of them.

Comment: So what is i want to store the read more selector in a var so it doesnt need to access the dom each time but refers to all the read-more-toggle elements in the dom